# SendEmail having issues, any alternatives?

Tags: sendmail, smtp

As opposed to writing something else, I'm looking for an alternative to sendemail or maybe even some help with trying to fix the issues I'm experiencing.

I've always used sendemail with absolutely no problems in the past. It seems like just recently is where I started having issues trying to connect to a mail server over TLS/465. Always connected to the exact same server before and it appears that it doesn't work against any server that supports SSL/TLS on SMTP server.

Here's what I get back when trying to use it:

```
sendemail -f [from email] -t [destination email] -u "test subject" -o message-file=email.html -s mail.privateemail.com:465 -xu [my username] -xp [my password] -vvvv -o tls=yes
Aug 24 10:22:22 case sendemail[20173]: DEBUG => Assigned $opt{} key/value: tls => yes
Aug 24 10:22:22 case sendemail[20173]: DEBUG => Connecting to mail.privateemail.com:465
Aug 24 10:22:22 case sendemail[20173]: DEBUG => My IP address is: x.x.x.x
Aug 24 10:22:32 case sendemail[20173]: ERROR => mail.privateemail.com:465 returned a zero byte response to our query.
```

I can connect to mail.privateemail.com:465 with openssl and everything works flawlessly, so I'm not sure what the deal is with sendemail. I've tried upgrading the libraries that it use but still no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to capture the traffic with tcpdump/ssldump and look at it. From the looks of it, the TLS handshake is failing. It could just be a matter of TLS versions your client or server supports.

I assume this works fine without SSL?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Their server apparently doesn't accept non-SSL connections. They claim they accept TLS on 25 and 26, but I can't see those ports opened (not even from a VPS that doesn't have any outbound port restrictions). Just 465/SSL

Comment: Try port 587 ("submission").  That's open and supports STARTTLS.

Comment: That works for me! Also confirmed with namecheap that they've just performed an upgrade and is currently testing with port 25/26. 587/TLS works for me. Thanks so much man!